# Cards that I created in Bootstrap 4 are not responsive when changing screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created some Cards using bootstrap, html and css. Unfortunately, when I change the size of the screen the cards do not adjust accordingly.

This is how they look right now before changing the size.

[image]

When I go to inspect and switch it to ipad, it looks like this:

[image]

I tried using a media query in my css folder to solve this, but no luck. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? **EDIT: Ideally, I would like to have one card on top of another when changing the screen size. I would also like to have the spacing in between the cards as well.**

```
<div class="col-md-4">       
   <div class="ScoreCard">
      <div>
         <h3 style="background-color:@item.TitleColor"> @item.ReportName - @item.TitleColor  </h3>
       </div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
     <div style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:35px;">
         <h1>GrossAmountDue</h1>
     </div>
</div>
 <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:35px;">
     if (Flag == 1)
       {
        <i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size:30px; color:red; margin-left:15px;"></i>
       }                                      
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div>
       <p style="font-size:20px; margin-left: 25px;">Audited </p>
       <p style="font-size:20px; margin-left: 25px;">Packages: Will go here</p>
       <p style="font-size:20px; margin-left: 25px;">Transactions will go here</p>
       <p style="font-size:20px;"Icon will go here</p>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <p style="margin-left:17px;">Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
//CSS
<style>
    .ScoreCard {
        background-color: orange;
        width: 500px;
        min-height: 200px;
        border: 15px black;
    }

    @@media screen and (max-width: 100px){
        .col{
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Columns and rows must exist within containers in Bootstrap. Also, show the head of your document please

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your cols in a row like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this way, when you have a screen equal or less of md, contents of cols goes one on top of another, but when screen is lg or higher, you have 3 cols in a row.

**INFO**

In your media query you are changing the `col` class, when instead you are using `col-md-4`

Comment: How can I change it then in my media query?

Comment: You shouldn't use media query but grid system, wrapping cols in rows